# Send array from view to controller and getting null expection error

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4

I am using JQuery to create arrays of data from an HTML table, and I need to pass those arrays into a controller method in ASP.NET MVC 4.

```
var data = {
InstallationControls: array_installationControl,
HardwareGUIDs: array_HardwareGUID,
InstallAppIDs: array_InstallAppID,
MACAddresses: array_MACAddress
};

$.ajax({
url: "@Url.Content("~/Home/ActivationManagement")",
type: "POST",
data: {data: data},
success: function(){
   console.log('success!!');
}
})

public class MACAddress
    {
        public String Key { get; set; }
        public String Value { get; set; }
    }
public class MyViewModel
    {
        public List<MACAddress> MACAddresses { get; set; }
    }

public ActionResult ActivationManagement(MyViewModel model)
{
List<MACAddress> listOfMacAddresses= model.MACAddresses;
}
```

But I am getting a NullReferenceException saying that my listOfMacAddresses object is null. Do I do it wrong? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Please, add HttpPost into your code as follows:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult ActivationManagement(MyViewModel model)
{
   List<MACAddress> listOfMacAddresses= model.MACAddresses;
   return View();
}
```

and be careful that which model you pass in ajax method. The parameter in the action method isn't correspond to view model in ajax post.